# MySQL - Checkboxes - 1 or 0

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I'm trying to post a checkbox value to my MySQL database. For some reason this code does not work when checking whether the value is set to 0/1.

Could anybody point me in the right direction. I know how to POST up for normal text/select input types but am having real difficulty with checkboxes and radio buttons.

createNewsArticle.php - View

```
<br /> Featured
<input type="hidden" name="featured" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="featured" value="1" checked />
<br />
```

createNewsArticle.php - Controller

```
$featured = isset($_POST['featured']) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: You have two fields which will be posted with the same name, but different values. What do you get in the whole $_POST?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way checkboxes work is either it's on or it is not there at all, so if you are overwriting same field, it won't work, optimal approach would be:

`<br /> Featured
<input type="checkbox" name="featured" value="1" checked />
<br />`

now in PHP, you'll check if the value of featured like:

`$featured = isset($_POST['featured']) ? 1 : 0;`

While this is not tested, I think it should work.